# Можно ли задать .serialize() параметры?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма с чекбоксами, на нее подвязан serialize(), который хватает соответственно атрибуты `name` и `value`. Получается: `checkbox=1&checkbox=2`. Мне нужно добавить некоторые параметры. Чтобы это выглядело так: `?params&checkbox=1&checkbox=2` Есть ли возможность как-то передавать в `serialize` параметры, или же надо уже после сериализации руками это править?

Comment: Дак в [документации](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) же написано *This method does not accept any arguments*. Serialize не принимает параметров. Можно просто создать функцию, которая выполнит необходимую сериализацию, а в конце просто добавите нужные параметры и вернете готовую строку. Ваша функция уже сможет принимать аргументы.

Comment: За вас уже написали функцию ) - serializeArray()

Answer (score 1):

serialize не принимает параметры, если вам надо строку такого вида получить, то самый простой способ изложен ниже. Если передавать через Ajax будете, то проще указать url уже нужный вам.

```js
var txt = '?params&'+$('#form1').serialize()
alert (txt)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" action="">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="aaa">
  <input type="text" name="familyname]" value="bbb">
  <input type="text" name="year" value="cccc">
  <button type="submit">отправить</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, речь идёт о get-запросе.
Просто укажи дополнительные параметры в самом url, на который делаешь ajax.

Comment: подобные сообщения лучше делать в комментариях

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/234421)

Comment: @Sublihim, почему не является?